# Catapult Arm rotation - libgdx and box2d

Tags: rotation, libgdx, box2d, revolute-joints

I'm currently working on a catapult game with box2d but I have encountered a problem regarding the rotation of the arm of the catapult.

Let me explain a little bit about my catapult:

I have 2 objects.
* The catapult arm - Dynamic Body
* The catapult base - Static Body

I want the catapult arm to rotate back and forth within a certain range.
Here is an image of my catapult:
http://i.gyazo.com/7ce4dfa87b2083a0eb62df7c4acd3e47.png

Now, I tried to "link them" using joints but it didn't work. Initially, I want the arm to be bent a little bit to the left.
I have my own Game World object that contains the Box2d world object and all the game objects. Moreover, I have an object that is called Game Renderer which takes care of the rendering in the game. Here is what I have tried so far in my Game World object:

```
package com.david.gameworld;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.joints.RevoluteJointDef;
import com.david.objects.CatapultArm;
import com.david.objects.CatapultBase;

public class GameWorld{

    private World b2dWorld;
    private CatapultArm arm;
    private CatapultBase base;
    private RevoluteJointDef jointDef;
    public GameWorld() {
        // Initialize The Box2d World
        b2dWorld = new World(new Vector2(0,0),true);
        initializeObjects();
    }
    public CatapultArm getArm() {
        return arm;
    }
    public CatapultBase getBase() {
        return base;
    }
    public World getBox2DWorld() {
        return b2dWorld;
    }
    public void updateWorld(float delta) {
        b2dWorld.step(1/delta, 8, 5);
    }
    private void initializeObjects() {
        // Initialize The Objects(Catapult, Base)
        arm = new CatapultArm(b2dWorld);
        base = new CatapultBase(b2dWorld);
        jointDef = new RevoluteJointDef();
        jointDef.initialize(arm.getBody(), base.getBody(), new Vector2(120,62));
        jointDef.enableMotor = true;
        jointDef.enableLimit = true;
        jointDef.motorSpeed = -1260;
        jointDef.lowerAngle = (float) Math.toRadians(90);
        jointDef.upperAngle = (float) Math.toRadians(75);;
        jointDef.maxMotorTorque = 4800;
        b2dWorld.createJoint(jointDef);
    }
}
```

CatapultArm and CatapultBase are both objects in my game that contains all the configurations of the bodies(position,type,etc).

Here are the codes:

CatapultBase.java

```
package com.david.objects;

import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;

public class CatapultBase extends ObjectInWorld{

    public CatapultBase(World world) {
        super(world);
        initiate();
    }
    @Override
    protected void initiate() {
        //The Body
        bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
        bodyDef.position.set(140f, 62f);
        body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    }
}
```

CatapultArm.java

```
package com.david.objects;

import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;

public class CatapultArm extends ObjectInWorld{

    public CatapultArm(World world) {
        super(world);
        initiate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void initiate() {
        //The Body
        bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position.set(154f, 62f);
        body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    }
}
```

ObjectInWorld.java

```
package com.david.objects;

import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;

public abstract class ObjectInWorld {

    protected BodyDef bodyDef;
    protected Body body;
    protected World world;
    protected ObjectInWorld(World world) {
        this.world = world;
    }

    protected void initiate() {

    }
    public float getX() {
        return body.getPosition().x;
    }
    public float getY() {
        return body.getPosition().y;
    }
    public Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }
}
```

How can I "pin" the catapult arm to the base so that it would rotate nicely?

Comment: Please define "didn't work".

Comment: it suppose to bent slightly to the left because of the limits I set up(9 degrees to 75 degrees) but it doesn't. I think I have a problem with the way I use coordinates.

Comment: Well what does it do instead? You have the lower limit set higher than the upper limit, that is generally not a good idea.

Comment: Nothing happens. It doesn't rotate at all.

Comment: Try correcting the limit settings.

Comment: I already tried. It seems that the positions of the bodies/joint are incorrect but I don't know where exactly is the error.

Comment: Perhaps the bodies are being obstructed by some other bodies? What happens when these two bodies are the only two in the world?

Comment: Just noticed your bodies don't have any fixtures on them. In the original C++ version at least, this would cause them to have no density, and therefore no mass, so they would be treated as fixed rotation. Do these bodies rotate when the joint is removed?

Comment: Yea ok. I managed to "pin" to the ground body but now I'm trying to make the arm draggable, rotating it back and forth. How can I do this?

Comment: Look at the mouse joint example in the Box2D testbed. You might want to start a new question if the subject has changed now.

Comment: Could you please help me out on this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077818/revolute-joint-rotation-box2d

Answer (score 0):

Your bodies don't have any fixtures on them. In the original C++ version at least, this would cause them to have no density, and therefore no mass, so they would be treated as fixed rotation.